# How to animate jquery effects simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, effects

for example I have 2 jquery effects and 3 object:

```
$('.test1').fadeIn();
$('.test2').fadeOut();
$('.test3').fadeOut();
```

when .test1 fades in .test2 and .test3 must fade out simultaneously.
how can I do it **without** extra plugin and without opacity animation?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the callback for achieving the same

```
$('.test1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $('.test2').fadeOut();
      $('.test3').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: @bodz , that is the only way you will know that test1 fadin is completed...i think

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".test1").fadeIn("fast",function(){$(".test2,.test3").fadeOut()});
```